# Tikz: nested styles on 3 levels, how to refer to arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to create a bunch of styles, where each style can choose to put the content either inside the node [image] or outside [image]. I managed to do that, but I also would like to be able to force one behavior for one given style.

So I tried to create a function which forces this behaviour, but it creates nesting of tikz styles on 3 levels... and unfortunately I can't find how to refer to arguments in that setting: because `#1` refers to the argument of the first level, and `##1` refers to the second level, I was expecting `###1` to refer to the third level... but it does not compile.

***MWE:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  my global style/.style={
    mynode/.style={fill=red,rounded corners=1mm},
    my default label style/.style={
      above, font=\tiny
    },
    add content/.style={
      %% By default, adds the content at the end of the node
      execute at begin node=##1,
      %% But we would like to be able to force this behaviour later:
      %label={[my global style, my default label style] ##1},
    },
    %% /!\ uncomment these lines, it will break:
    % force content in label/.style={
    %   add content/.style={
    %     % ##1 should be the argument of "add content" and ###1 should be the argument of "add content"
    %     label={[my global style, my default label style,##1] ###1},
    %   },
    % },
    % force content in label/.default={},
  }
  ]
  \node[my global style, mynode, add content=Abc] {};
  %% Goal: make this work
  % \node[force content in label, add content=Abc] at (2,0) {};
  % \node[force content in label=below, add content=Abc] at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `####1` instead of `###1`. The number of `#`s doubles, not steps by 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!